# Problems with Clean URLs

Tags: 7, .htaccess, uri

I've got a problem with Clean URLs. I had a look around and my problem doesn't look like any thing else on this site or anywhere on the internet.

I have a *.htaccess* file. It's there and it's working. I know because I've set it to remove www. and it is.

I go to *Configuration->Search and Meta->Clean URLs* (some people don't pass the clean URLs test but I do, it doesn't even come up) I have the option to turn on Clean URLS:

---

[image: enable clean URLS]

---

I tick the box and click Save configuration. But this happens:

---

[image: Bloody doesn't work]

---

NO! I ticked you!

So if I go to a clean URL (/contact) it works. But in the menu it comes up as (/?q=contact).

I thought I'd hack the database and turn it on.

But it was on the whole time... 
<hold flashlight under chin and look scary>

Does anyone know how to remedy this situation so it stays ticked and comes up clean in the menu?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, alright. I'm not going to kill anyone.

Turns out there was a line in my *settings.php* file:

> $GLOBALS['conf']['clean_url'] = 0;

Commented it and everything worked just fine.

That was 2 hours of my life wasted...